# Server Error in '/' Application with System.Net;

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document

I have it error after use HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse.
How i can fix it?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error    Description: An application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error from being viewed.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on the local server machine, please create a 
>   tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root
>   directory of the current web application. This  tag
>   should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable
>   the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to
>   "Off".

```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
> 
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
>     </system.web> </configuration>
>
```

> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
> 
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
>     </system.web> </configuration>
```